# Match any number (or negitive number) except '-0'

Tags: regex

I have the followin RegEx to match any number between 1 and 4 digits in length, with a `-` character if so desired.

```
^[-]?\d{1,4}$
```

However, I'd like to exclude from the list of possible matches `-0`.  I've tried the following, but it seems to break everything.

```
^[-]?(?!-0)\d{1,4}$
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Do you also want to match "-03" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the excluding group before :

```
^(?!-0)-?\d{1,4}$
```

Note that you don't have to put the minus sign between brackets.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that! Thank you, that's what I needed, although I amended slightly to `(?!-0$)` so that strings such as `-012` will match (I'll strip out the leading 0 later).

Comment: @DavidGard I wondered about this, hence the comment under your question.

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
^(?!-?0)[-]?\d{1,4}$
```

This won't match any number that begins with "0" or with "-0".

If you want to match numbers beginning with "0" but not with "-0", use:

```
^(?!-0)[-]?\d{1,4}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Just by concatenating positive and negative numbers:

```
^([0-9]{1,4})|(-[1-9][0-9]{0,3})$
```